# Escrever em um arquivo .txt com laço 'for' no Python

Tags: python, arquivo

Preciso que um arquivo .txt guarde o último serial gerado, para das próximas vezes que for executado esse arquivo ser lido e continuar a sequencia. Ou seja, se o ultimo serial(serial2) gerado for o número 6 quero que seja guardado o número 6 no txt para que na proxima execução do código ele inicie no 6. Estou usando o txt como um "Banco de Dados".

```
def GerarSerial(start_at=int(open('ultimaos.txt', 'r').readlines(0)[0])+1):
    serial = f'{start_at:0>5}'
    serial2 = f'{start_at+1:0>5}'
    with open('ultimaos.txt', 'w') as ultimaosarquivo:
        ultimaosarquivo.write(serial2)
    with open('ultimaos.txt', 'r') as ultimaosarquivo:
        ultima_os = ultimaosarquivo.readlines(0)[0]
    return f'{ultima_os:0>5}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(3):
        GerarSerial()
        print(GerarSerial())
```

ultimaos.txt:

```
00006
```

Porém ao executar o código ele apenas repete o valor 3 vezes.

Comment: Artur a pergunta não está muito clara, da para melhorar? Vlw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você definiu um valor *default* para o parâmetro `start_at`. E [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), esse valor só é avaliado uma vez, quando a função é criada, e depois não muda mais:

> ***Default parameter values are evaluated from left to right when the function definition is executed**. This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used for each call.*

Ou seja, quando você cria a função, o `start_at` terá o valor default com base no conteúdo atual do arquivo, somado com 1. E para todas as chamadas feitas sem nenhum argumento, será usado o valor inicial que ele tinha. Por isso que, não importa quantas vezes você chame a função, o mesmo valor está sendo usado.

Sendo assim, retire este parâmetro. Dentro da função você tem que sempre ler o valor atual e somar 1:

```py
def GerarSerial(arquivo='ultimaos.txt'): # acho que faz mais sentido o nome do arquivo ser um parâmetro
    try:
        # tenta ler o arquivo
        with open(arquivo, 'r') as arq:
            atual = int(arq.read()) # como o arquivo só tem uma linha, lê tudo
    except OSError:
        # se o arquivo não existe, começa um novo serial
        # mas também poderia dar erro, você decide o que faz mais sentido para o seu caso
        atual = 0

    # calcula o novo serial (no caso, soma 1 com o atual)
    serial = f'{atual + 1:0>5}'
    with open(arquivo, 'w') as arq: # atualiza o arquivo
        arq.write(serial)
    return serial

for _ in range(3):
    print(GerarSerial())
```

Como o arquivo sempre tem apenas uma linha, não precisa de `readlines` para ler todas as linhas e depois pegar a primeira. Basta usar `read` para ler tudo (mas também poderia ser `readline()` - no singular - para ler a primeira linha).

Claro que faltou verificar se o conteúdo é um número mesmo, mas a ideia geral é essa: se o arquivo não existe, começa um novo serial (mas poderia dar erro, você decide o que faz mais sentido para o seu caso), e se existe, lê o conteúdo dele.

Depois basta somar 1 e gravar o novo serial no arquivo, e retornar este serial. E veja que não precisa abrir de novo o arquivo para ler o que você acabou de gravar, pois isso já está na variável `serial`.